# GROK LOG Filter / grep specific values

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logging, database-replication, logstash-grok

i am a noob at GROK and I need to grep specific things from a logfile

Here is an example of the log:

```
2021-03-16 12:23:30,717 [ STATUS ] {replicate_changes             }  Replication status: SRC_SCN 1235720653409 - SRC_TMSTMP 2021-03-16 12:23:27 - STMTS/s 189.18 - TX/s 101.05
```

From that line I need to grep for:

1. Timestamp
2. Value for STMTS/s
3. Value for TX/s

In regex it would look something like this:

```
(^\d.+) \[ .+ \].+ SRC_TMSTMP (\d.+) - STMTS\/s (\d.+) - TX\/s (\d.+)
```

Can anyone help me solve this mystery? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Note the original question asked for timestamp, and the sample regex appears to be capturing both the (presumably) receipt timestamp and "SRC_TMSTMP".  The simple grok pattern below will capture both and assign appropriately:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA} SRC_TMSTMP %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:source_timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA} STMTS/s %{BASE10NUM:stmts_per_sec:float} %{GREEDYDATA} TX/s %{BASE10NUM:tx_per_sec:float}
```

This could be further optimized based on additional sample data.

General grok syntax and usage is explained here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/grok-processor.html

Pre-defined grok patterns can be found here:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.11/libs/grok/src/main/resources/patterns/grok-patterns

In short, grok pattern matching follows the format:

```
%{DEFINED_GROK_PATTERN:field_name:optional_cast_type}
```

Note if no `field_name` is specified, it will not assign the captured value to a field - essentially the same as using a regex pattern without parentheses, or a non-capturing group.

Usage of this pattern depends on where you intend to use it - Elasticsearch or Logstash (based on the question tags).  If Elasticsearch, see the first link - if using Logstash, see the following: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Note a useful tool in Kibana is the Grok Debugger, which can be found under Dev Tools:
[image]

Comment: Hi, 

thx for the detailed explanation and for the solution! :)